# Requisições entre Web e CLP Siemens pequeno delay

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

Esta função Jquery é controlada quando um Switch da minha página é realizado um change

```
$("#statusM1").change(function () {

        if (statusM1 == 0) {
            url = "index.html";
            name = '"motor"';
            val = 1;
            sdata = escape(name) + '=' + val;
            $.get(url, sdata, function (result) { });
        } else if (statusM1 == 1) {
            url = "index.html";
            name = '"motor"';
            val = 0;
            sdata = escape(name) + '=' + val;
            $.get(url, sdata, function (result) { });
        }
    });


$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function () {
        $.get("IOCounter.html", function (result) {

            statusM1 = result.trim();
            $('#counter').text(statusM1);

            if (statusM1 == 1) {
                $('#statusM1')[0].MaterialSwitch.on();
            } else {
                $('#statusM1')[0].MaterialSwitch.off();
            }

        });
    }, 1000);
```

**setInterval tem a funcionalidade de coletar um dado da página IOCounter.html**

O script acima esta funcionando mas percebo que na hora do change há um delay uma pequena confusão no momento do change e a requisição.

**$.get(url, sdata, function (result) { });**

Explicando um pouco melhor temos o seguinte cenário:

1ª Inicialmente o Switch esta na posição ON,

2ª então ao clicar ele vai para o OFF,

3º e com isto executa a função .change,

4º temos um  intervalo em que a requisição não é feita então o Switch volta para o ON, pois ainda não recebeu o verdadeiro valor do setInterval.

5ª após esta pequena confusão no Switch pega o valor correto da requisição e volta para o OFF

O que tem de ser feito para que amenize este inconveniente ?

Comment: Não use `setInterval` para fazer requisições. Use `setTimeout`.

Comment: Tente fazer desta forma: http://jsfiddle.net/1gL3h7zn/

Comment: @sam é o seguinte como pode acontecer de desligarem ou ligarem o equipamento no local a página tem que atualizar pois senão vira a maior bagunça, entendeu , e mais outra todos os eletricistas uns 15 terão acesso então imagina só a bagunça um liga o outro desliga, entendeu, o porque do setInternal

Comment: @sam como sou novato em JQuery foi o primeiro comando que encontrei na internet, se você tiver sujestão será muito bem vinda.

Comment: Sugeri usar setTimeout porque as requisições serão feitas em fila, uma após a outra. Usando setInterval as requisições serão feitas de forma desorganizada, ou seja, irá fazer uma requisição atrás da outra sem querer saber se a anterior tenha sido processada. Isso pode travar o navegador e até fazer com que o servidor suspenda o acesso por achar que está havendo abuso (se ele tiver essa proteção) ou criar um gargalo. A sugestão que coloquei apenas organiza as requisições, e a página será atualizada da mesma forma.

Comment: @sam funcionou, ai te pergunto qual diferença entre setInterval e setTimeout ? este sistema Web fica hospedado em um CLP Siemens que é uma controladora muito usada em automação Industrial.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80258/discussion-between-sam-and-cyberlacs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme discutido nos comentários, utilizar requisições Ajax com `setInterval` não é indicado porque ele é assíncrono ao processamento do Ajax. O retorno do Ajax pode levar milissegundos ou até alguns segundos, logo chamar requisições com um intervalo pré-definido pode criar um gargalo no servidor ou travar o navegador.

O indicado é usar `setTimeout` após o processamento do Ajax. Desta forma cada requisição será feita de forma ordenada e em fila.

Para isso, coloque o Ajax dentro de uma função e chame-a novamente após o retorno:

```
function f(){
  $.get("IOCounter.html", function (result) {

      statusM1 = result.trim();
      $('#counter').text(statusM1);

      if (statusM1 == 1) {
          $('#statusM1')[0].MaterialSwitch.on();
      } else {
          $('#statusM1')[0].MaterialSwitch.off();
      }
      // chama novamente a função após 1 segundo, criando um loop
      setTimeout(f, 1000);
  });
}

// chama a função após 1 segundo.
setTimeout(f, 1000);

// Ou, se esse segundo inicial não for necessário
// pode chamar a função sem intervalo com

f();

// removendo a linha setTimeout(f, 1000); acima
```

Lembrando que a função do `$.get` só será chamada se o Ajax for bem sucedido. Caso haja algum erro, o `setTimeout` não será chamado e o loop irá parar. Por isso é melhor chamar o `setTimeout` no callback `.always` para garantir que a função será sempre chamada novamente:

```
function f(){
  $.get("IOCounter.html", function (result) {

      statusM1 = result.trim();
      $('#counter').text(statusM1);

      if (statusM1 == 1) {
          $('#statusM1')[0].MaterialSwitch.on();
      } else {
          $('#statusM1')[0].MaterialSwitch.off();
      }
  })
  .always(function(){
      // chama novamente a função após 1 segundo, criando um loop
      setTimeout(f, 1000);
  });
}
```